# Converting SOSI to ESRI Shape

Tags: mac, sosi

I need a tool for converting norweigan SOSI files to ESRI Shape using a Mac. It could also be a command line tool for Windows.

I tried to build GDAL with SOSI support on my Mac following [instructions on this page](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/SOSI) but when I try compiling `fyba` I get this error message:

`INQTID.cpp:18:11: fatal error: 'sys/vfs.h' file not found`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found somewhere on the world wide web that instances with `sys/vfs.h` could be replaced with `sys/mount.h`. I have no idea what the difference is, but now it works.